# Correct VAD interface design with Java sound API?

Tags: java, interface, voice, audio

VAD stands for voice activity detection. I have a VAD algorithm and it works.

How to make it present itself in the ideology of Java sound API?

My few ideas are:

1) Create `TargetDataLine` each time voice detected and allow consumer to handle line creation and read created line.

Not sure if lines are for this.

2) Create `AudioInputStream` each time voice detected and allow consumer to handle stream creation and read it.

3) Have one constant `TargetDataLine` and send open/start/other events each time voice detected.

Which one is most beautiful?